# Why this .htaccess is not working correctly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following .htaccess I think that it should redirect **ALL** domains to laminova.com.ve

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$ 
RewriteRule (.*) "http\:\/\/laminova\.com\.ve\/cms\/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^koralite$ "http\:\/\/laminova\.com\.ve\/cms\/marcas\/koralite\/madera" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^zenolite$ "http\:\/\/laminova\.com\.ve\/cms\/blog\/productos\/218-zenolite-paneles-de-alto-brillo-y-apariencia-similar-a-la-del-vidrio" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^acquafloor$ "http\:\/\/laminova\.com\.ve\/cms\/blog\/productos\/178-innovacion-en-pisos-flotantes" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^duragloss$ "http\:\/\/laminova\.com\.ve\/cms\/blog\/productos\/217-duragloss-mucho-brillo-con-la-apariencia-de-la-mas-fina-laca" [R=301,L]

redirect 301 /formica http://laminova.com.ve/cms/marcas/formica/maderas
```

But while `www.laminova.com.ve/cms/blog/productos/255-formica-supera-la-prueba-de-lijado` 
redirects correctly to `laminova.com.ve/cms/blog/productos/255-formica-supera-la-prueba-de-lijado`

this url's:

```
http://www.laminova.sismsdns.com/cms/blog/productos/255-formica-supera-la-prueba-de-lijado
http://laminova.sismsdns.com/cms/blog/productos/255-formica-supera-la-prueba-de-lijado
```

don't redirect to `laminova.com.ve/cms/blog/productos/255-formica-supera-la-prueba-de-lijado`

I'm pulling my hair right now as I've tried a lot of variations founded in the web like

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^laminova.sismsdns.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.laminova.sismsdns.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://laminova.com.ve/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The domains must be using the same `.htaccess` if I break the file I get an error on all the domains.

```
httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.31 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug  4 2016 12:20:09
```

Comment: What's with the escapes in the rewriterule substitution? And this should get you an endless redirect, because you are not preventing requests going to `laminova.com.ve` from being rewritten again.

Comment: Yes but somehow the site is not going in a redirect loop, I've been meaning to ask about the escapes as I see a lot examples with and without the escapes. I have to admit I know next to nothing about apache rewrite rules.

Comment: First redirect rule will cause redirect loop. If that's not happening then this .htaccess is not being used.